# How to get Active process file name using windows forms application?

Tags: c#, winforms, winforms-interop

```
public static string GetActiveProcessFileName()
   {
       try
       {
           IntPtr hwnd = GetForegroundWindow();
           uint pid;
           GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, out pid);
           Process p = Process.GetProcessById((int)pid);
           // return p.MainModule.FileName;
           CommandLine = GetMainModuleFilepath((int)pid);
           if (CommandLine != null)
           {
               var array = CommandLine.Split('"');

               if (array.Length == 3)
               {
                   if (array[array.Length - 1].Equals(" "))
                   {
                       return "Application";
                   }
                   if (!array[array.Length - 1].Equals(" "))
                   {
                       return array[array.Length - 1];
                   }
                   return null;
               }
               if (array.Length == 5)
               {
                   return array[array.Length - 2];
               }
               return "Explorer";
           }
           return "Explorer";
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           ErrorLog.ErrorLog.Log(ex);
           return "Explorer";
       }
 }
```

Here "[CommandLine]" get current open file names correnctly..
if i run my application.executed successfully..Now 
i open 3 notepad files like abc.txt,aaa.txt,dde.txt one by one then,Which will opened file will be display as normal...

If i opened word documents 3 files one by one or excel files..I get only first opened file names saved only...
How can i get correct result of open document Why i got this problem when open word or excel or pdf file open situvation...

Comment: Not exactly sure what you are looking for, but beware that many applications are not creating new process for new document like notepad. One process does not mean one top level window, and  window title is not related to "document file name"...

Comment: firstly If i opened Ex.docx file ..then process file name is Ex.docx...It is in opened state...Now i open another word file Like Ex2.docx file...Now i want to display Ex2.docx is opened.But it shows First opened file Ex.docx name will be displayed every time...If i close Ex.docx file then it shows file name is Ok..

Comment: What do you mean "process file name"? (I'd expect it to be name of executable, but your comment shows document names)...

Comment: Yes process file names..either it may be word or excel or pdf file names

Comment: So is it possible to get the name/path of that second doc file ?

Answer (score 0):

use the below code to get the word file instances

```
 private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        y = GetActiveWindowTitle();

        try
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application WordObj;
            WordObj = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Word.Application");
            var vvv = WordObj.StartupPath;
                x = "";
                for (int i = 0; i < WordObj.Windows.Count; i++)
                {
                    object idx = i + 1;
                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Window WinObj = WordObj.Windows.get_Item(ref idx);

                    // doc_list.Add(WinObj.Document.FullName);


                    x = x + "," + WinObj.Document.FullName;

                    //x = WinObj.Document.FullName;
                }                                                         

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            // No documents opened
        }

        string[] ax=x.Split(',');
      //  string[] ax1 = x1.Split(',');




        ForAllWordFiles.Text = x;
        ForWordTitle.Text = y;
        if (y != null)
        {
            ActiveWord.Text = " ";
            if (y.Contains("- Microsoft Word"))
            {
                ForWordTitle.Text = y.Substring(0, y.Length - 17);


                foreach (var item in ax)
                {
                    if (item.Contains(ForWordTitle.Text))
                    {
                        ActiveWord.Text = item;
                        break;
                    }
                    ActiveWord.Text = " ";
                }

            }
        }


    }
```

this code is valid for 2010 office